# Problem with scanning gray qr code - zxing library

Tags: android, camera, qr-code, zxing

I have a problem with qr-code which is gray and white. The problem is that I can scan it when the environment around is dark, and when it is bright during the day, the camera doesn't catch either the contrast or the qr reader doesn't distinguish between colors that's why it's not readable. I am using a 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.13' library. Any ideas how I should change the contrast or set camera mode to monochrome or how to deal with it? Also I found an app in google play store which reads this code without problem so there must be a sollution.

[image]

Greetings

Answer (score -1):

Yeah... The QR code you use can be scanned by a lot of cameras... BUT zxiling supports BLACK and WHITE QRcodes only. You can use the built-in object Bitmap in android to work with the image... Also you should try to change the QR code with another

Comment: It supports also other colors than black and white. Tested it :) But thanks for reply